# jQuery selector for select tag whose name is an associative array - How to select it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple `select` tags with names as `d[brk1]`, `d[brk2]`, `d[brk3]` etc.

I'm trying to select all of them by using

```
var break_tags = $('select[name^="d[brk]"]'); // returns empty
```

However, if I use exact name instead of 'starts with'

```
var break_tags = $('select[name="d[brk2]"]'); // works
```

***What I tried***

```
var break_tags = $('select[name^="d\\[brk\\]"]'); // does not work
var break_tags = $('select[name^="d[]"]');     // no luck again
```

I'm unable to find a workaround this, though I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have inputs with `d[brkn]` where n is a number, you'll want this as your selector:

```
$('select[name^="d[brk"]')
```

Comment: Are you sure it's typed correctly? I tried it anyways..doesn't work

Comment: My bad..it works. Cant select as answer just yet...asking me to wait for 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be:

```
$('select[name*="d[brk"]')
```

Comment: Not quite.. *= is contains.  what he is doing is correct. He needs ^= which means "starts with"

Comment: Not sure if `*` is the correct way, but nonetheless I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: You're just missing the closing `]` to `[name*=`